# Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0 error flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am getting this warning in my run console. Baically, my chatRoomTile is not been showed on the screen. It just shows blank screen, even after i have had chat with 10 persons.

It is just showing the main screen, and the red container for 2 seconds, as in conditional statement.

This is the output in run -

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86...
Restarted application in 1,522ms.
W/eyansh.whatsap( 6057): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->close()V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/DynamiteModule( 6057): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 6057): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 6057): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
Lost connection to device.
```

Here is my code -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp/helper/authenticate.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp/helper/constants.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp/helper/helperFunctions.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp/screens/search.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp/services/database.dart';

class ChatRoom extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChatRoomState createState() => _ChatRoomState();
}

class _ChatRoomState extends State<ChatRoom> {

  AuthMethods authMethods = new AuthMethods();
  DatabaseMethods databaseMethods = new DatabaseMethods();
  Stream chatRoomStream;

  Widget chatRoomList(){
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: chatRoomStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return snapshot.hasData ? ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ChatRoomTile(
              snapshot.data.documents[index]["chatRoomId"],
          );
       }) : Container(color: Colors.red,);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
   getUserInfo();
    super.initState();
  }

  getUserInfo() async{
    Constants.myName = await HelperFunctions.getUserNameSharedPreference();
    databaseMethods.getChatRooms(Constants.myName).then((val){
      setState(() {
        chatRoomStream = val;
      });
    });
    setState(() {

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff161517),
          title: Text(
            'WhatsApp',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white54,
              fontSize: 20.0,
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            Container(
              height: 25.0,
              width: 25.0,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: "btn1",
                backgroundColor: Color(0xff161517),
                child: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white54,),
                onPressed: (){
                },
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){
                authMethods.signOut();
                Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Authenticate()));
              },
              child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.exit_to_app,
                    color: Colors.white54,
                  ),
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){
              },
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1.0),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.more_vert,
                  color: Colors.white54,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: chatRoomList(),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          heroTag: "btn2",
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SearchScreen()));
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.message,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChatRoomTile extends StatelessWidget {

  final String userName;
  ChatRoomTile(this.userName);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
               image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("assets/images/DefaultPhoto.png"),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
               ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 8.0,),
          Text(
            userName,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,

            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If anyone wants details for any widget, you can ask me.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Add the following permission to `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`,
before `<application>` starts:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: can confirm this to be working :) Adding tiny more info to the location.

Comment: I have this line, but the warning is still alive and I can debug my app only on the 30% runnings

Comment: Currently at December 2021, this not fix the issue. It might be something else.

Comment: <manifest xlmns:android...>

 ...

<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> # add here

<application ...

</manifest>

But this does not remove the issue as Richardd mentioned.

Comment: This did work for me. I was trying to do Google Sign-In with Firebase so maybe a slightly different use-case (in-case anyone sees this answer and think it's not worth trying).

Comment: I have cross-checked everything added his permission and checked every on firestore documents but nothing is working for me. I am keep getting this error [my warning on console](https://freeimage.host/i/DlNIx2)

Comment: I added, it is not working, still got the same warnings

Comment: Can confirm this is working in August 2023

Answer (score 9):

**Why it comes?**

It's because your emulator doesn't have internet connection. Though it is showing wifi connection.

**Solution:**

1. first of all check your internet connection status.
2. Go to Emulator and turn off wifi and then again turn on wifi. That's it.

Also, don't forget to add the below code to the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

before `<android>`

Comment: Turning off and turning on wifi trick worked. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad to know that's your problem is solve. hope it will help others also.

Comment: I'm glad to know that's your problem is solve. hope it will help others also.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error. I looked through my code and found that I had given the wrong collection name while I was calling firebasefirestore. Please do check that you are providing the right reference names to collections and docs.

Comment: They are all same

Answer (score 2):

I see this error when wireless is active but the connection to Firestore fails. For example, when debugging I connect to the local emulators, if I forget to start the emulator I get this message, but the app still works from cache.

Comment: I connected via cable, still got the error

Answer (score 0):

just make sure you are calling the right instance name from firestore
for me i was calling medicinal product in the instace and i had defined MedicineProductData int the firebase database so correcting it to the MedicineProductData solved my issue

code:
QuerySnapshot value =
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("MedicineProductData").get();