Flutter White blank screen on run
I have asked this question before and was trying to solve it since about 2 weeks ago.
I'm working on social app, when the applications runs the HomeScreen supposed to be displayed, but i got a blank white screen instead.
here's the screen:
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const route = 'HOME';


  //final postRefreshKey = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
  HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: NestedScrollView(
            floatHeaderSlivers: true,
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            headerSliverBuilder: (context, isScrolled) => [
              SliverAppBar(
                systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
                  statusBarColor: Colors.white,
                ),
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                floating: true,
                leadingWidth: 75,
                leading: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(ProfileScreen.route);
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: CurrentUser.user.image == null
                          ? NetworkImage('temp image')
                          : NetworkImage(CurrentUser.user.image!),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                title: Text('Zagel'),
                actions: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.settings,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ],

                elevation: 0,
                scrolledUnderElevation: 0,
              ),
            ],
            body: Column(
              children: [

                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 50,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                  ),
                  child: TabBar(
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(
                        text: 'Posts',
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        text: 'Chats',
                      ),
                      Tab(
                        text: 'Users',
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: TabBarView(
                    children: [
                      PostScreen(key: UniqueKey(),),
                      ChatsScreen(key: UniqueKey()),
                      ListView.builder(
                        key: UniqueKey(),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            height: 120,
                          ),
                        ),
                        itemCount: 60,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Here's the output on the console:
D/ProfileInstaller( 9813): Installing profile for com.example.chat
I/FirebaseApp( 9813): Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
W/DynamiteModule( 9813): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 9813): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 9813): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
D/nativeloader( 9813): Configuring clns-5 for other apk /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.jar. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/app/~~dZhK9M2-DGHa74skVj_LEQ==/com.google.android.gms-80d5rWtOrST573zkVHpHYQ==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~dZhK9M2-DGHa74skVj_LEQ==/com.google.android.gms-80d5rWtOrST573zkVHpHYQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms
D/nativeloader( 9813): Extending system_exposed_libraries: libvraudio_client.qti.so:libbinauralrenderer_wrapper.qti.so:libhoaeffects.qti.so:libQOC.qti.so:libSloganJni.oplus.so:libsuperNight_mtk.oplus.so:libupdateprof.qti.so:libQOC.qti.so:libdiag_system.qti.so:libqape.qti.so:libqesdk_ndk_platform.qti.so:liblistenjni.qti.so
W/ziparchive( 9813): Unable to open '/apex/com.android.extservices/javalib/android.ext.adservices.dm': No such file or directory
W/ziparchive( 9813): Unable to open '/apex/com.android.extservices/javalib/android.ext.adservices.dm': No such file or directory
D/nativeloader( 9813): Configuring clns-6 for other apk /apex/com.android.extservices/javalib/android.ext.adservices.jar. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/app/~~dZhK9M2-DGHa74skVj_LEQ==/com.google.android.gms-80d5rWtOrST573zkVHpHYQ==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~dZhK9M2-DGHa74skVj_LEQ==/com.google.android.gms-80d5rWtOrST573zkVHpHYQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms
D/nativeloader( 9813): Extending system_exposed_libraries: libvraudio_client.qti.so:libbinauralrenderer_wrapper.qti.so:libhoaeffects.qti.so:libQOC.qti.so:libSloganJni.oplus.so:libsuperNight_mtk.oplus.so:libupdateprof.qti.so:libQOC.qti.so:libdiag_system.qti.so:libqape.qti.so:libqesdk_ndk_platform.qti.so:liblistenjni.qti.so
D/nativeloader( 9813): InitApexLibraries:
D/nativeloader( 9813):   com_android_appsearch: libicing.so
D/nativeloader( 9813):   com_android_art: libartservice.so
D/nativeloader( 9813):   com_android_conscrypt: libjavacrypto.so
D/nativeloader( 9813):   com_android_extservices: libtflite_support_classifiers_native.so
D/nativeloader( 9813):   com_android_os_statsd: libstats_jni.so
D/nativeloader( 9813):   com_android_tethering: libandroid_net_connectivity_com_android_net_module_util_jni.so:libcrypto.so:libframework-connectivity-jni.so:libframework-connectivity-tiramisu-jni.so:libmainlinecronet.114.0.5735.84.so:libservice-connectivity.so:libservice-thread-jni.so:libssl.so
D/nativeloader( 9813): Configuring clns-7 for other apk /system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/app/~~dZhK9M2-DGHa74skVj_LEQ==/com.google.android.gms-80d5rWtOrST573zkVHpHYQ==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~dZhK9M2-DGHa74skVj_LEQ==/com.google.android.gms-80d5rWtOrST573zkVHpHYQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms
D/nativeloader( 9813): Extending system_exposed_libraries: libvraudio_client.qti.so:libbinauralrenderer_wrapper.qti.so:libhoaeffects.qti.so:libQOC.qti.so:libSloganJni.oplus.so:libsuperNight_mtk.oplus.so:libupdateprof.qti.so:libQOC.qti.so:libdiag_system.qti.so:libqape.qti.so:libqesdk_ndk_platform.qti.so:liblistenjni.qti.so
D/nativeloader( 9813): Configuring clns-8 for other apk /system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/app/~~dZhK9M2-DGHa74skVj_LEQ==/com.google.android.gms-80d5rWtOrST573zkVHpHYQ==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~dZhK9M2-DGHa74skVj_LEQ==/com.google.android.gms-80d5rWtOrST573zkVHpHYQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms
D/nativeloader( 9813): Extending system_exposed_libraries: libvraudio_client.qti.so:libbinauralrenderer_wrapper.qti.so:libhoaeffects.qti.so:libQOC.qti.so:libSloganJni.oplus.so:libsuperNight_mtk.oplus.so:libupdateprof.qti.so:libQOC.qti.so:libdiag_system.qti.so:libqape.qti.so:libqesdk_ndk_platform.qti.so:liblistenjni.qti.so
D/nativeloader( 9813): Configuring clns-9 for other apk /data/app/~~dZhK9M2-DGHa74skVj_LEQ==/com.google.android.gms-80d5rWtOrST573zkVHpHYQ==/base.apk. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~dZhK9M2-DGHa74skVj_LEQ==/com.google.android.gms-80d5rWtOrST573zkVHpHYQ==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~dZhK9M2-DGHa74skVj_LEQ==/com.google.android.gms-80d5rWtOrST573zkVHpHYQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms
V/NativeCrypto( 9813): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 305 native methods...
W/om.example.cha( 9813): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
I/ProviderInstaller( 9813): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
W/om.example.cha( 9813): Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/om.example.cha( 9813): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
I/om.example.cha( 9813): Background concurrent copying GC freed 370676(18MB) AllocSpace objects, 13(288KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 4483KB/8966KB, paused 407us,98us total 110.059ms

I have already searched a lot about the causes of blank screen, and didn't worked.
It's running on an android physical device.

so do you  mean that its failed to run on emulator?

@pmatatias no it's running on an emulator too and giving the same blank screen,  as the console appears in the question there's no error or even a warning, but still got a white blank screen

probably the issue not in your provided code. I copy you code, change the PostScreen and ChatScreen with Container widget and also comment the NetworkImage , the widget works fine, I have 3 Tab in my screen

and also , make sure your device has internet access. since you are using Firebase .
based on your log, you need to add internet permission to your AndroidManifest https://stackoverflow.com/a/73669662/12838877

it's working when replace tabbar views with container, so the problem with the PostScreen !, i fgiured it out the problem occurred because of bad widget structure in post screen (nested listviews), thank you @pmatatias
